# Error while converting varchar to smalldatatime

Tags: sql, sql-server

Well, I have a problem with sending data. There are three stations, all of which work on-site on an ongoing basis. I checked the system settings and settings and one of the stations was updated to the 21H2 version (I set everything up as it is at the station where it works). Unfortunately, this option did not help. I also turned off the error on the server by setting it on the station.

[I'm adding an error dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6JNU.png)

Comment: What is a "station", and what does "21H2" mean?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Though even if you put the error as text, it's not in English, so you will need to translate it.

Comment: I'm assuming "station = computer" and "21H2 = Windows 10, Release 21H2". But even if that is true, it does not really help in describing what your actual problem is. You either need to provide a self-contained example that exhibits the issue, or provide more details about you are doing, what is happening, and what you expect to happen.

Comment: The most likely problem is that your logic involves an implicit conversion of a string to smalldatetime and you have relied on (perhaps accidentally without realizing) settings that affect that conversion. Find the application code that generates the error and post it if you do not understand how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I think SQL Server assumes another format than the one you
intended and another value causes the error.

```
Use CONVERT(smalldatetime, YourColumn, 101) to force format mm/dd/yyyy, or
use CONVERT(smalldatetime, YourColumn, 103) to force dd/mm/yyyy.
```

To prevent this in the future:

- Always store dates as a datetime or smalldatetime column.
- When you have to convert character data to datetime, always use one of
  the unambiguous formats:

- For date only: yyyymmdd
- For date plus time: yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.mmm (where the optional .mmm
  part denotes the milliseconds)